# Tibbles and data-defined column names

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I'm using tibbles in my own functions, that commonly accept variable names as arguments. So basically, instead of doing

```
tibble %>% do_something(foo)
```

I do a lot of

```
function(bar){
  tibble %>% do_something(bar)
}
```

I'm puzzled with the different ways of defining column names, depending on the context: although it works by trial and error, and I'm starting to understand why, I'd value a clear summary + explanation. Some functions want a character vector with the names of the columns (they are the simplest to use), some want, I think, symbols (correct me if I'm wrong), sometimes neither works, sometimes both, sometimes different approaches work but give different results :

```
bar
get(bar)
!!!rlang:::sym(bar)
all_of(bar)
```

Let's explore :

```
ds <- tibble(aa=c(1,2,3),bb=c(4,5,6))

myvar <- "aa"
myvars <- c("aa","bb")
```

***1) Firstly, we have functions that seem to work with char-vectors:***

**Argument is explicitly described as char:**

```
ds %>% left_join(ds,by=myvar)
```

**Argument is described as tidy-select:**

```
ds %>% select(all_of(myvars)) # Ok
ds %>% select(myvars)
# NOT ds %>% select(get(myvar))
ds %>% select(!!!rlang::syms(myvars))
```

Ok, so here already I do not understand. select() accepts a string or strings vector, or a symbol. But why does it not accept get(myvar) ? The value of myvar is the string "aa", so why is it not equivalent to  `ds %>% select("aa")` ?

```
ds %>% summarise(across( all_of(myvars), max ))
ds %>% summarise(across( myvars, max ))
# NOT ds %>% summarise(across(get(myvars),max))
# NOT ds %>% summarise(across( !!!rlang::syms(myvars) , max ))
```

Although `across()` claims to accept a tidy-select syntax, this seems to be true only in a restricted sense (it accepts chars but not symbols, unlike select that digests both).

***2) Then, we have functions that seem to work with symbols:***

**Arg is "variables or computations to group by" = a symbol ?**

```
ds %>% group_by(!!!rlang:::syms(myvar) )
ds %>% group_by(get(myvar))
ds %>% group_by(all_of(myvar))
# But NOT ds %>% group_by(myvar)
```

All three work but give different results...

**Arg is data-masking**

```
ds %>% count(get(myvar))
ds %>% count(!!!rlang::syms(myvar)) 
# But:
ds %>% count(all_of(myvar))# Works, but NOT the same result !

ds %>% filter(get(myvar)==1)
ds %>%  filter(.data[[myvar]] == 1) 
# NOT ds %>% filter(!!!rlang:::syms(myvar)==1)

ds %>% mutate(cc=myvar) # Works, but fills cc with the string "aa"
ds %>% mutate(cc=get(myvar))
ds %>% mutate(cc=.data[[myvar]])
# NOT ds %>% mutate(cc=!!!rlang::syms(myvar))

ds %>% mutate(myvar=11) # Works, by creating a column called "myvar"
ds %>% mutate(.data[[myvar]] * 0 +11) # Works similarly
# NOT ds %>% mutate(get(myvar)=11)
# NOT ds %>% mutate(!!!rlang::syms(myvar)=11)
```

**Finally...**

We introduce a brand new syntax here !

```
ds %>% mutate("{myvar}" := 11)
```

**Arg is "specification of columns to expand"**

```
ds %>% complete(!!!rlang::syms(myvars))
# NOT ds %>% complete(get(myvars))
# Error: Join columns must be present in data.
# x Problem with `get(myvars)`.
```

there is a known issue with

```
# NOT ds %>% complete(myvars)
# NOT ds %>% complete(all_of(myvars))
```

In principle, it should be possible to pass the names of the cols using tidy-select syntax (all_of), however as of early 2021 this does not work (https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/1033)

So, in a  nutshell: could somebody explain me when (and why) to use the following ?

```
bar
get(bar)
!!!rlang:::sym(bar)
all_of(bar)
"{myvar}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues are in `group_by`, it would be with `across`

```
ds %>%
     group_by(across(all_of(myvar)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   aa [3]
#     aa    bb
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     4
#2     2     5
#3     3     6
```

or with `count`

```
ds %>% 
   count(across(all_of(myvar)))
```

Similarly

```
 ds %>% 
     mutate(!! myvar := 11)  
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     aa    bb
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1    11     4
#2    11     5
#3    11     6
```

The `complete` step works

```
ds %>% 
    complete(!!!rlang::syms(myvars))
# A tibble: 9 x 2
#     aa    bb
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     4
#2     1     5
#3     1     6
#4     2     4
#5     2     5
#6     2     6
#7     3     4
#8     3     5
#9     3     6
```